# Joining three tables in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, join

I have three tables in MSSQL for a game which are structured as follows:

CHARS
This is the look up table it has:

- strAccount which is linked to the primary key of NGSCUSER it is the
  account username
- strChar01 which is the first character slot
- strChar02 which is the second character slot
- strChar03 which is the third character slot

these have the primary key of the gameuser table inside they are character names

NGSCUSER

- strUserID account username
- strPasswd account password

GAMEUSER

- strUserId this is the character name
- sRank whether the character is a game master

What I need to be able to do in is compare the login details against the PHP variables $username and $password in the query and most importantly check their associated character and find out whether it has a sRank of 1

I assume I need a three table join of some kind but I don't know how to go about it any examples or help would be much appreciated

This is the query I've tried to build so far but it errors on the third line with incorrect syntax near 'CHARS':

```
SELECT NGSCUSER.strUserID, NGSCUSER.strPasswd, GAMEUSER.sRank 

FROM 'CHARS'

INNER JOIN NGSCUSER ON NGSCUSER.strUserId = CHARS.strAccount
INNER JOIN GAMEUSER ON GAMEUSER.strUserId = CHARS.strChar01
INNER JOIN GAMEUSER ON GAMEUSER.strUserId = CHARS.strChar02
INNER JOIN GAMEUSER ON GAMEUSER.strUserId = CHARS.strChar03


WHERE NGSCUSER.strUserId='$username' and NGSCUSER.strPasswd='$password' and GAMEUSER.sRank = '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to literally answer your question (which probably doesn't solve your problem), you need to alias your tables to join multiple tables:

```
select * from [chars] c
inner join ngscuser n on n.strUserId = c.strAccount
inner join gameuser g1 on g1.strUserId = c.strChar01
inner join gameuser g2 on g2.strUserId = c.strChar02
inner join gameuser g3 on g3.strUserId = c.strChar03
where n.strUserId='$username' and n.strPasswd='$password' and g1.sRank = '1'
```

However, if you're trying to pull back the `gameuser` row that matches any character slot, then you need to use `in`:

```
select n.strUserID, n.strPasswd, g.sRank 
from [chars] c
inner join ngscuser n on n.strUserId = c.strAccount
inner join gameuser g on g.strUserId in (c.strChar01, c.strChar02, c.strChar03)
where n.strUserId='$username' and n.strPasswd='$password' and g.sRank = '1'
```

And, now that I have your attention, I would like to do the following PSAs:

1. I hope you're sanitizing `$username` and `$password` so that you are not susceptible to SQL injection.
2. Do ***not*** store passwords in plaintext. You should only be storing them as salted hashes. If you can do a `select * from ngscuser` and get everybody's password, shame on you. Shame. Shame. Shame.

Comment: the database(s) aren't mine unfortunately I'm aware of the dangers of plain text passwords, sql injection protection is my next task I notice mssql doesn't have mysql_real_escape_string(); so I'm going to need something to replace that

Comment: @arcanine - Use parameterized queries. More here: http://blogs.iis.net/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should be just CHARS not 'CHARS'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample function to handle something like you are asking for:

```
function functionName($username,$password){

    SELECT tablename.colname AS alias, tablename.colname2 AS alias2, ...
    FROM tablename tn
    JOIN talbename tn2  on tn2.colname = tn.colname
    JOIN anothertable tn3 on tn3.colname = tn2.colname

    WHERE tn.colname = $username AND rl.password ='$password'
    AND tn3.colname = 1
 }
```